# Outlook's autocomplete isn't working for only a couple of addresses

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, autocomplete

So I'm following this article to get autocomplete working:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/contacts/autocomplete-not-working-correctly-in-outlook-2010#if-you-have-a-microsoft-exchange-server-account

It works for all but only a couple of email addresses and one in particular. I've rebuild outlook profiles, roamcache and stream_autocomplete, and reinstalled and tried with cached exchange vs without but still have the issue. The web app, however, will show the autocomplete for this email.

To reproduce, I try autocomplete with a known address that isn't available, then send an email to that address, and then autocomplete for that new entry begins working immediately. But when I send an email to the problem address, it still won't complete.

I also created a contact for this email to try and help, but it still isn't listening to the name or email address.

I've run NK2View from nirsoft and I can see this email address does exist in the list. What am I missing?

Comment: What is different between the addresses that work and those that do not? Are some linked through Linked In, for example? Are some in a particular group, e.g., one you don't manage?

Comment: Hopefully it may provide some guidance: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2134480-outlook-autocomplete-not-working,